# How do i make every value of objects in a array as String

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, filter

I have an array of object something like this

```
[{id:1, name: "alexander"},{id:2, name: "the great"}]
```

What is the best way to make the value of all keys as string in the array. So the result should be

```
[{id:"1", name: "alexander"},{id:"1", name: "the great"}]
```

Note: My Object is very big and is a combination of number and strings or null and also there is no permanent index of the key in the object. The key in the object can come in any order. Though the key will be at the same place for all the objects. So the desired result should have all the value of all objects in the array as a string.

Comment: what do you expect for an object or `null`/`undefined` or date instance? what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` to iterate the items. In the map's callback, destructure the objects, extract the `id` use rest syntax to get the other properties of the object. Convert the id to a string via the `String()` factory, and then rebuild the object using the spread syntax.

Note: If you expect `null` or `undefined` ids, you can use the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`) to get a default value. For example, `String(id ?? '')`.

```js
const arr = [{id:1, name: "alexander"},{id:2, name: "the great"}]

const result = arr.map(({ id, ...rest }) => ({ id: String(id ?? ''), ...rest })) 

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array` `forEach` method.

```
users.forEach(user => user.id = user.id.toString())
```

where `users` is the array of objects.

You can try it here:

```js
let users = [{id:1, name: "alexander"},{id:2, name: "the great"}];
users.forEach(user => user.id = user.id.toString()); 
console.log(users)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function to iterate each object and save it in each array.

```js
var list = [{ id: "1", name: "alexander" }, { id: "1", name: "the great" }]

var namesValues = list.map((item) => {
  return item.name;
});
var idValues = list.map((item) => {
  return item.id;
});

console.log(namesValues);
console.log(idValues);
```